# Pace.js no funciona

Tags: javascript, html

Pace.js es una barra animada de JavaScript de carga de la página. Sitio oficial:
https://github.com/HubSpot/pace

Mi código HTML:

```
<head>
<script src="//raw.githubusercontent.com/HubSpot/pace/v1.0.0/pace.min.js"></script>
    <link href="resources/pace.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

Gracias.

Comment: Intenta mejor descargar los archivos y llamarlos de manera local.

Comment: No es muy clara la pregunta, ¿no funciona de que manera? ¿no te carga el script? ¿este no hace lo que debería hacer? específica más detalles para poder ayudarte mejor

Comment: ¿Algún mensaje de error en la consola?

Answer (score 3):

### Problemas

- No puedes usar `//raw.githubusercontent.com/HubSpot/pace/v1.0.0/pace.min.js` para incluir el archivo `JS`, ya que los encabezados que devuelve esta `URL` son `text/plain`.
- *Opcional*: No has descargado el `CSS` de alguno de los `themes` existentes.

### Soluciones:

- `JS` opciones:

  - Descargar el archivo `pace.min.js` desde la `URL`
  - Utilizar un `CDN`, por ejemplo, `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pace/1.0.2/pace.min.js`
- `CSS` opciones:

  - Descarga el `CSS` de alguno de los [`themes`](http://github.hubspot.com/pace/docs/welcome/) y metelos en un archivo.
  - Utiliza un `CDN`, por ejemplo, `https//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pace/1.0.2/themes/black/pace-theme-flash.min.css`

### Demo:

```js
$(function(){
  // Esperar 1 segundos y cargar ALGO infinitas veces
  function cargarAglo() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $.ajax({
        url: '//www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/Nature-Beach-Scenery-Wallpaper-HD.jpg'
      }).always(cargarAglo);
    }, 1000);
  }
  
  cargarAglo();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pace/1.0.2/themes/black/pace-theme-flash.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pace/1.0.2/pace.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```