# ¿Cómo crear un pantallazo de carga?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Aunque la pregunta es bastante genérica, no quiero nada en específico. Solo una idea para seguirla y trabajar sobre ella.

Lo que quiero es que muestre un pantallazo de carga antes de mostrar el contenido de mi aplicación web.

Preguntas:

- ¿Se conseguiría poniendo un div que ocupe toda la pantalla con un z-index superior al contenido?
- ¿El icono de carga es simplemente un png rotando?
- ¿Cómo juego con los tiempos?. Es decir, ¿Hago que no se quite ese elemento de carga hasta que no se hallan cargado todos los elementos que hay por debajo?.

Como digo, solo quiero una idea general, para trabajar sobre ella.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Si realizas acciones mientras se carga la página, yo lo que hago es definir una función de carga, en dónde se activa un div en position fixed desde 0,0 hasta 100vw, 100vh con z-index superior al resto. Luego, cuando termino de realizar mis cosas, le hago un fadeOut. Lógicamente, puedes poner una barra de progreso que puedes ir actualizando según vayas completando las tareas de carga, aunque por lo general, un gif de fondo centrado, transparente y con animación infinita es suficiente. También tienes ganchos para saber cuando se han cargado las imágenes, así que también puedes controlar eso.

Comment: Mira esta pregunta( https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/63892/15855)  que trata de usar una libreria JS (http://github.hubspot.com/pace/docs/welcome/) encargada de poner una progress bar mientras las imagenes o pagina carga. Igual eso te da ideas o sirve para tu proyecto. Un saludo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo uso siempre los Spinners (puedes incluir algo de texto dentro de ellos, como cargando... etc.

Lo único que tienes que hacer es ocultarlo o mostrarlo segun te convenga.

Te dejo aqui un ejemplo.

```css
.loader {
    border: 16px solid #f3f3f3; /* Light grey */
    border-top: 16px solid #3498db; /* Blue */
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes spin {
    0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

```html
<div class="loader"></div>
```